# how to insert new data inside an array attribute of a model in backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I am a begineer to Backbone.js. I have a model  as:

model Class= `TPS` and model instance name= `tpsInfo`

Model Data as:

```
{
  "range": "",
  "rangeid": "",
  "maxrange": "",
  "minrange": "",
  "q_category_id": "1",
  "tpsInput": [
    {
      "q_id": 1,
      "q_text": "Need support for Geographic redundancy (GR)?",
      "data_type": "2",
      "meta": "NULL",
      "answer": "" // should be added here !!!
    },
    {
      "q_id": 2,
      "q_text": "Number of Redundant sites",
      "data_type": "1",
      "meta": "0",
      "answer": "" // should be added here !!!
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a form in template which when filled should add the entered values in **answers** to the model. Template:

```
<script type=text/template id="quesTable">
  <% for(i=0;i<tpsInput.length;i++) { %>
    <tr> <td><%= tpsInput[i].q_text %></td>
    <td>
    <%  if(  tpsInput[i].data_type == 0)
    {

    }
  else if(tpsInput[i].data_type == 1)
    {
      %>
      <input type='text' id="<%= tpsInput[i].q_id %>" class='form-control' placeholder='Enter value'  >
    <%  }
  else if(tpsInput[i].data_type == 2)
    {
      %>
      <input type=checkbox id="<%= tpsInput[i].q_id %>" >
    <%  } %>
    </td></tr>
  <%  } %>
</script>
```

How to insert the entered value of form to **answer** attribute present in tpsInput array inside model.Kindly help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Backbone originally does not provide an ability to populate models directly from html inputs (like in Angular), you should listen to input changes from your Backbone.View instance, and then update model in code when event happens. Here you have a Backbone.Model and a template instances, I suppose you have a Backbone.View instance too. You should take a look at a Backbone.View property `events` (http://backbonejs.org/#View). So, you can attach events to inputs like

```
events: {
   'keyup input[type="text"]': 'textAnswer',
   'change input[type="checkbox"]': 'checkboxAnswer'
}
```

Giving an example of code how I see it all together:

```
var TPS = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // ...
  updateAnswer: function(questionId, answer) {
    var tpsInput = this.get('tpsInput');
    for (var key in tpsInput) {
      if (tpsInput[key].q_id == questionId) {
        tpsInput[key].answer = answer;
      }
    }
    this.set('tpsInput', tpsInput);
  }
  // ...
});

// ...
var tpsInfo = new TPS();
// ...

var TPSView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    model: tpsInfo,
    events: {
       'keyup input[type="text"]': 'textAnswer',
       'change input[type="checkbox"]': 'checkboxAnswer'
    },
    textAnswer: function(ev) {
      var $el = $(ev.currentTarget);
      var questionId = $el.attr('id'); // get question id
      var answer = $el.val();
      this.model.updateAnswer(questionId, answer);
    },
    checkboxAnswer: function(ev) {
      var $el = $(ev.currentTarget);
      var questionId = $el.attr('id'); // get question id
      var answer = $el.is(':checked');
      this.model.updateAnswer(questionId, answer);
    }
    // ...
});
```